# AngularJS & Cordova $http issues - browser works fine, app does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cordova, http

I am writing a Phonegap/Cordova application using AngularJS consuming a Rails API. I'm attempting to use `$http` to hit the API during a login event. When emulating my application on Chrome (launching using `cordova run`) $http works great as expected.

However, anytime I use `$http` on the actual PhoneGap developer app, it will error out and never hit the API.
Rails API is using the gem `rack-cors` to allow CORS - it works with several other AngularJS applications and is relatively unsafe only for debug purposes.

```
# config/application.rb

CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN  = "*"
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = %w{GET POST PUT OPTIONS DELETE}.join(',')
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = %w{Content-Type Accept X-Auth-Token AllowedHeader}.join(',')

... other config stuff ...

config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => :any
  end
end

config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  => CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN,
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" => CORS_ALLOW_METHODS,
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS
}
```

What I've tried:
 1) update phonegap `config.xml` to unsafely allow anything access

```
<access origin='*' 
        allows-arbitrary-loads-in-media='true' 
        allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content='true' 
        allows-local-networking='true' />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

2) use angular `.run` to add headers for every request made

```
angular.module("services")

.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common['AllowedHeader'] = "origin";
})
```

3) manually build up each request with other headers

```
login: function(credentials) {
  var request = {
    url: baseURI + "/user_sessions/",
    method: "POST",
    params: {
      user_session: credentials,
    },
    headers: {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }

  return $http(request);
}
```

4) use `cordova-whitelist-plugin`

Any thoughts out there? I've seen many questions referencing how `$http` is working in browser but failing on the phone.

Comment: Are you facing this issue only in development mode of the app? Keep in mind that you can easily setup a proxy, and that will solve the issue.

Comment: Could you expand on the piece about setting up a proxy? We are looking to use the actual phone for demos, would be great to have something that can use $http even if it's a proxy

Comment: Check this example: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-proxy-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not with $http, but rather the path $http was given during the POST. Our baseURI variable was set to `//api.site.com` which worked fine with a browser but not with the mobile app. Changing it to be more explicit `https://api.site.com` worked great.